# Is z3_dbg.dll still part of the distribution?

Tags: z3

In the last release of Z3, I didn't get z3_dbg.dll. Is it still released ?

Alexandre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We stopped including `z3_dbg.dll` in Z3 2.14. The main motivation was to reduce the distribution size. z3_dbg.dll is quite big, and it is not used by most users. That being said, we realize this DLL is useful when developing applications on top of Z3 API and/or writing Z3 theory plugins. We will include it back in the Z3 distribution package, or create a separate debug distribution package.